# How many 3-digit numbers are there such that 8 is the largest digit?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

This is my attempt so far:

Let $A_{1}$ be a set of 3-digit numbers that contain 8's, $A_{2}$ be a set of 3-digit numbers that contain 9's.

Then, by subtracting the number of **3-digit numbers that do not contain 8's** from the total number of 3-digit numbers, I obtain $\left | A_{1} \right |=(9 \times 10 \times 10)-(8\times 9 \times 9)=252$.

Similarly, $\left | A_{2} \right |=(9 \times 10 \times 10)-(8\times 9 \times 9)=252$.

since $ A_{1} \cap A_{2}$  is the set of 3-digit numbers that contain both 8's and 9's, so $A_{1} \setminus (A_{1} \cap A_{2})$ is the set of 3-digit numbers such that '8' is the largest digit (which is the desired set for answering this question).

However, I am not sure how to find $ \left | A_{1} \cap A_{2} \right |$.

Can someone please help me on this? Or if you have other better alternatives in solving this question, please let me know.

This is a question under the chapter about the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Can't you use the same method to find \left | A_{1} \cap A_{2} \right |? Start with the total number of 3-digit numbers and subtract the ones that do not contain either 8 or 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an alternative approach.

Let $A_1$ be the set of three-digit positive integers with largest digit $8$ that have an $8$ in the hundreds digit.

Let $A_2$ be the set of three-digit positive integers with largest digit $8$ that have an $8$ in the tens digit.

Let $A_3$ be the set of three-digit positive integers with largest digit $8$ that have an $8$ in the units digit.

Then, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, we need to find 
$$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3| = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$$

$|A_1|$

Since both the hundreds digit and the largest digit in the three-digit positive integer are equal to $8$, we have nine choices for the tens digit (since we cannot use $9$) and nine choices for the units digit (for the same reason).  Hence, $|A_1| = 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 = 81$.

$|A_2|$

Since both the tens digit and the largest digit in the three-digit positive integer are equal to $8$, we have eight choices for the hundreds digit (as both $0$ and $9$ are excluded) and nine choices for the units digit (since $9$ is excluded).  Hence, $|A_2| = 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 = 72$.

$|A_3|$

Since both the units digit and the largest digit in the three-digit positive integer are equal to $8$, we have eight choices for the hundreds digit (as both $0$ and $9$ are excluded) and nine choices for the tens digit (since $9$ is excluded).  Hence, $|A_3| = 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 1 = 72$.

Can you take it from here?